# How to pass variable in Realm query Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, database, realm

```
NSString a;
NSString b; 
RealmDatabaseTimeStamp *timeStamp = [[RealmDatabaseTimeStamp objectsWhere:@"activityEnableTimeStamp =="@b,@"Id=="a] firstObject];
```

This gives an error "unexpected tokedn after the string in objective c" about passing variable in the query. Any clue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm's query using `NSPredicate`. The syntax is same as NSPredicate's one. You can use `%@`, `%@` is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string, number, or date.

```
NSString a;
NSString b;
RealmDatabaseTimeStamp *timeStamp = [[RealmDatabaseTimeStamp objectsWhere:@"activityEnableTimeStamp = %@ AND Id = %@", b, a] firstObject];
```

You can see more details on [NSPredicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Comment: Although this answer is valid, that specific error is saying he has invalid characters after his strings. In fact, the problem is that he's trying to **concatenate** strings without a valid operand or method. `activityEnableTimeStamp =="@b` should be `[@"activityEnableTimeStamp ==" stringByAppendingString:b]` and `@"Id=="a` should be `[@"Id==" stringByAppendingString:a]` (maybe the syntax for Realm is wrong too and this answer fixes it, but I'm just noticing what the error says).